# Session variable of N-1 instead of N

Tags: php, jquery

I have a timer in jquery and i would like to keep the value when i refresh the page. I am using php session variable with some ajax. But when i refresh it keeps the value of N-1 instead of N.

Example :

I am at 20 second when i refresh nothing happens. Then when i refresh back at 18 seconds it is the 20 seconds who outputs

Here is the code :

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_GET['number'])) {
$_SESSION['timer']=$_GET['number'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cookie.js"></script>

        <script>

$(window).unload(function() {

var number = $('#test').text();
alert(number);
          $.get('divb.php',{number:number},function(resultat){
                        return false;                                                       
                });



});         


$(document).ready(function(){


var numb = 30 ;                 
var numba = 100 ; 

function comptage() {

setTimeout(comptage,1000);
$('#test').html(numb);
$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: numba });

numb -- ;
numba = numba - (numba/numb) ;


if (numb < 0 )
{

numb = 0 ; 
numba = 0 ;
}



};

comptage();












    });     







            </script>   


<style >

#affichage_point

{
position:relative;
    background-color:  #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid  #7375D8;
width:450px ; 
height:5px ; 
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 100px;

   padding:30px;

}

   #progressbar  {

  width : 400px ;

  }


  #progressbar > div {

  background: #7375D8;

  }


#bardivs {
    width:400px; 
     position:absolute;
      top:12px;
      left: 50px;


     }

#test {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
}



</style>






   </head>


    <body>


    <div id = "affichage_point">
    <div id="bardivs">
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
    <div id="test"></div>
    </div>
    </div>


<?php   if (isset($_SESSION['timer'])) { ?>
     <div id ="r6"><?php echo $_SESSION['timer'] ?> </div> <br/> 
     <?php } ?>


        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use this code:

So we just keep the first visit time and generate elapsed time. No need to store this variable in query (GET)

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['start_time'])) {
    $_SESSION['start_time'] = time();
}

$elapsedTime = time() - $_SESSION['start_time'];
```

But you gotta reset start_time somehow, guess when a user decide to start over

Comment: Hello vladim. In fact i really need to have the variable numb created on the function settimeout to be stored on the session variable. In fact if i create the session['timer'] on a click of jquery the variable is stored and output the good number. But when i do it in an unload it doesn't work. I am wondering if the unload of jquery don t leave enough time for the php page to take into account the session variable

Comment: Could you explain what you are working on? Buisiness processes please.

Comment: Yes. I need to build a multiple choice question with a timer of 30 seconds. Once the 30 seconds are passed you have yo go to the next question .  I don t want the user to refresh to page and have 30 seconds again,i want him to back to  the time where he was before the refresh. If he refresh at 18 secondes than he will have 18 seconds left to answer the question.

Comment: Why not refresh page after time is expires? So user opens the page, server outputs first question and resets timer, when time is up javascript refreshes the page and server outputs next question and so on. I think this is the easiest solution. Provide more code. I will rite you my own solution to this subject tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply i finaly understood your point with the start time. Thank you it works for me